# Pulseaudio card-profile for Focusrite Scarlett 18i8

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This is my first question here and I'm not quite sure what data to include for this question. Please ask me if you need me to provide more information.

I recently got the Focusrite Scarlett 18i8 Audiointerface. It's working really great in my DAW so far (using ALSA and manual channel assignment), but there is one annoying thing left:
Pulseaudio is recognizing the device as 7.1 output but the 18i8 has 4 stereo outputs!
Therefore VLC (and other apps) is playing movies in 7.1 mode and not stereo as it should.

I've googled around a bit and saw some things about Pulseaudio card-profiles and the pactl and pacmd commands. 
Thats why I tried:

```
pactl set-card-profile 3 output:analog-stereo
```

but it returns (translated by me):

```
Failure: no such entity
```

A look into

```
pacmd list-cards
```

tells why:

```
4 card(s) available.

...

index: 3
name: <alsa_card.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_18i8_USB_1000657A-00-USB>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 8
properties:
    alsa.card = "3"
    alsa.card_name = "Scarlett 18i8 USB"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Focusrite Scarlett 18i8 USB at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/sound/card3"
    udev.id = "usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_18i8_USB_1000657A-00-USB"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "1235"
    device.vendor.name = "Novation EMS"
    device.product.id = "8014"
    device.product.name = "Scarlett 18i8 USB"
    device.serial = "Focusrite_Scarlett_18i8_USB_1000657A"
    device.string = "3"
    device.description = "Scarlett 18i8 USB"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
profiles:
    output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Ausgang (priority 700, available: unknown)
    off: Aus (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-surround-71>
sinks:
    alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_18i8_USB_1000657A-00-USB.analog-surround-71/#2: Scarlett 18i8 USB Analog Surround 7.1
sources:
    alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_18i8_USB_1000657A-00-USB.analog-surround-71.monitor/#4: Monitor of Scarlett 18i8 USB Analog Surround 7.1
ports:
    analog-output: Analoge Ausgabe (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

The only profile available for this device is the analog-surround-71, but aplay lists all kinds of modes:

```
user@userbuntu:~$ aplay -L

...

sysdefault:CARD=USB
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 18i8 USB, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

So here is my Question:

Is it possible to manually add a Pulseaudio-profile or do i need to change anything deeper in ALSA? If so, could anybody tell me how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get a solution, I found [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=205859) in ArchLinux forums which seem yours?

Comment: believe it or not, that isn't mine! :D
I never got a solution, but a workaround in using jack2 with the pulseaudio jack-sink...
I'll have a look into the linked wiki as soon as i have time again.

Comment: Nice that you get a working workaround, Could you post it as answer with some instruction. That will be much helpful for new users, trying to figure out this. (I just post my findings as answer, so they can read about the current status)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create a pulseaudio profile to get the Focusrite 18i8 working in stereo.

Create the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/91-pulseaudio.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="pulseaudio1_end"
ACTION!="change", GOTO="pulseaudio1_end"
KERNEL!="card*", GOTO="pulseaudio1_end"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1235", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8014", ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="focusrite-18i8.conf"

LABEL="pulseaudio1_end"
```

And create the file `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/focusrite-18i8.conf`:

```
[General]
auto-profiles = no

[Mapping analog-out]
description = Analog Outputs
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = left,right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5
direction = output

[Mapping analog-in]
description = Analog Inputs
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = left,right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6,aux7,aux8,aux9,aux10,aux11,aux12,aux13,aux14,aux15
direction = input

[Profile output:analog-out+input:analog-in]
description = Analog Stereo
output-mappings = analog-out
input-mappings = analog-in
```

Then either restart the machine or run the commands:

`sudo udevadm trigger -ssound`

`pulseaudio -k`

In response to @Sneetsher: The Focusrite Scarlett 18i8 now seems to work well with Linux 3.19 and newer.  The internal mixer can be configured with `alsamixer` and the settings can be saved using `sudo alsactl store`.  It is also possible to change other settings (such as the impedance of the inputs between instrument (Hi-Z) and line level, or to switch the inputs' pad between 0 and -10dB) using alsamixer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the thing i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

From what I could collect, Focusrite Scarlett 18i8 internal mixer is not yet working with Linux/ALSA. It works only as direct audio input/output device.

- The manufacturer does not support Linux

  > ## [Linux and Focusrite / Novation products](https://focusritedevelopmentteam.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/linux-and-focusrite-novation-products/)
  >
  > A number of our users have been asking for help using Saffire 6 USB on
  >   Linux.  Before we get to that, I thought it would be useful to clarify
  >   our interfaces status on Linux, then I’ll post up some information
  >   that will be useful for brave driver developers wanting to attack the
  >   devices that don’t work.
  >
  > Please note that this is cobbled together from the back of my head, so
  >   might well be inaccurate – I’ll endeavor to correct and update it as
  >   best I can.
  >
  > Finally, please understand that Focusrite does not officially support
  >   Linux.  Although some people are seeing positive results in the
  >   comments, and some of our products are “known to work”, your mileage
  >   may vary.  Good luck!

  You can read down in the comment about some development  initiatives. As I check two github repository, they seem dead projects.

  https://github.com/smilingthax/alsa-driver_scarlett 
  https://github.com/trrichard/ScarlettMixer

  The first has [a non merged pull request](https://github.com/smilingthax/alsa-driver_scarlett/pull/1) of a Linux kernel v3.8.0 patch for s18i8 mixer.
- Here another thread from ALSA mailing list: [[PATCH] ALSA: usb-audio: Add quirk for Focusrite Scarlett 18i8](http://alsa-devel.alsa-project.narkive.com/WvcSqWeS/patch-alsa-usb-audio-add-quirk-for-focusrite-scarlett-18i8)

  > Re-testing this, I see that you are right. The mixer still doesn't
  >   work, but at least its usable for playback/recording/midi. Ignore this
  >   patch then.
  >
  > Thanks,
  >   --chris j arges